# How to use platformRequest to call a website Url?

Tags: java, java-me, midp

I am making a j2me website launcher for an url "http://www.google.com".

I am using this code:

```
public class LuncherMidlet extends MIDlet {
    boolean Isflage;
    public void startApp() {
        Isflage = false;
        try {
            Isflage = platformRequest("http://www.google.com");
        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(Isflage){
            destroyApp(true);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }
    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

This code is working fine, but when I try to close the browser of mobile it shows a message for connect to server. If I say no then it again open the this j2me launcher again. It's not exiting from mobile browser. My launcher reaches in a loop.
Kindly suggest me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke [platformRequest()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#platformRequest%28java.lang.String%29), it would call to native apps, and on close on browser it is browser's stuff that is being invoked. You can't change it.